# Will Photo Stream go away when iCloud Photos leaves beta?

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

iOS 8.1 is out and there is a public beta for iCloud Photos.

There are many differences between the new iCloud Photo service and the old Photo Stream, but for the scope of this question I am only concerned about my iCloud storage space. One of the major drawbacks of iCloud Photos is that it counts against your iCloud storage quota. The current Photo Stream feature, however, does not. It is effectively "free".

My question is this:

Does anyone know if Photo Stream will go away when iCloud Photos is finished and released in iOS 8.2 (or whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation until Apple makes an official announcement.

Given that the [iCloud Photos page](https://www.apple.com/icloud/photos/) doesn't mention Photo Stream once, and refers to "shared albums" instead of shared Photo Streams, I would guess that Photo Stream will be retired, yes.

Comment: Apparently newly created appleid's may not have photo stream available.